# Многопоточное программирование. Ошибка: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте, у меня такая проблема: Моё консольное приложение парсит онлайн магазин с большим количеством товаров. Структура парсинга такова:

1. Используя `Parallel.For` я пробегаю по всем каталогам.
2. В каждом каталоге используя `Parallel.For` я пробегаю по всем подкаталогам и так рекурсией, пока не дойду до каталога нижнего уровня с товарами.
3. Узнаю количество страниц с товарами в данном каталоге и используя `Parallel.For` пробегаю по всем страницам, заходя на информацию о каждом продукте.

В каждом каталоге около 30000 товаров. Проблема в следующем: информация о каталогах сохраняется быстро, но как дело доходит до продуктов, начинаются проблемы. В логе только и вижу `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.` Все запросы у меня делаются из одной функции

```
   public static string GetDataFromUrl(string url, ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> proxy)
{
    string data = "";
    WebRequest request = null;
    try
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxy.Keys.ElementAt(0), proxy.Values.ElementAt(0));
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("kobyb", "nbzbnbzb");
        request.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("kobyb", "nbzbnbzb");
        request.Timeout = 120000;
        ((HttpWebRequest) request).KeepAlive = false;
        ((HttpWebRequest) request).ReadWriteTimeout = 120000*2;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 200;
        if (request != null)
        {
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    data = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
                        return GetDataFromUrl(url, ProxyWorker.NextProxy);
                }
                response.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        return GetDataFromUrl(url, ProxyWorker.NextProxy);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Так же в App.config поставил

```
   <system.net>
    <connectionManagement>
      <add address="www.contoso.com" maxconnection="200" />
      <add address="*" maxconnection="200" />
    </connectionManagement>
  </system.net>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
```

В catch ловятся постоянно ошибки вида Time Out. В результате база поначалу заполняется быстро, потом скорость заполнения резко снижается , вываливается ошибка `Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. {Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation.}` Помогите пожалуйста, что мне сделать ?Без паралельности программа работает, но будет выполняться несколько месяцев.Что я делаю не правильно? Если всё дело в 2 гигабайтах и памяти просто реально не хватает, то как можно по другому оптимизировать весь этот процесс? Если я буду пробегать по каталогам обычным циклом и создавать для каждого каталога свой новый процесс, это может мне помочь, или дело вообше не в этом?

Показываю кусок одной из функций, которая вызывает request:
В этой функции происходит сохранение продукта(вся информация собирается и сразу сохраняется)

```
private void ParseProductInfoFromMotoAllegro(string link, IEnumerable<HtmlNode> columns, int parentId)
    {
        try
        {
            var name = columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "cellName");
            var nameDock = new HtmlDocument();
            nameDock.LoadHtml(name.InnerHtml);
            var nameNode = nameDock.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");
            var avatar = GetImage(columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "cellPhoto"));
            var prices = columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value == "cellPrice");
            var timeSales = columns.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("cellTime"));

            var timeSalesDock = new HtmlDocument();
            timeSalesDock.LoadHtml(timeSales.InnerHtml);
            var timeSalesNode = timeSalesDock.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span");

            var parseData = ParseDetailProductInfo(link);
            double priceExpression = 0;
            foreach (var price in prices.ChildNodes.Where(x => x.Name == "span"))
            {
                var value = price.InnerText.RemooveSimbols().ConvertToRuble();
                if (value > priceExpression)
                    priceExpression = value;
            }

            var resultPrice =
                Formula(priceExpression
                        + double.Parse(parseData.First(x => x.Key == "PriceTransport").Value[0]));

            Products product = _productRepository.CreatProduct(nameNode[0].InnerText.RemooveSimbols(),
                Translater.Translater.Translate(nameNode[0].InnerText.RemooveSimbols()), resultPrice,
                timeSalesNode[0].InnerText.RemooveSimbols(),
                parseData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "DescriptionOriginal").Value,
                parseData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "DescriptionTranslate").Value, link, parentId);

            var prod = _productRepository.Save(product);
            if (avatar != null)
            {
                avatar.ProductID = prod.ProductId;
                Save(avatar);
            }

        }
```

и вот в ней начинают сыпаться exception о том что не хватает памяти

private ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> ParseDetailProductInfo(string link)
{

```
bool flag = false;
HtmlDocument htmlDock = null;
HtmlDocument htmlNode = null;
while (!flag)
{
    try
    {

        flag = true;
        htmlDock = CheckFirstData(link);
        htmlNode = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlNode.LoadHtml(htmlDock.GetElementbyId("paymentShipment").InnerHtml);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        flag = false;
        ProxyWorker.IncCurrentIndex();
    }
}

ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>> result = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<string>>();
try
{

    var dd = htmlNode.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dd");
    double priceTransport = 0;
    if (dd != null)
        foreach (var d in dd)
        {
            var dChild = d.ChildNodes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "strong");
            //если не равно null и не бесплатная доставка
            if (dChild != null && !dChild.InnerText.Contains("wysyłka GRATIS"))
            {
                var ruble = dChild.InnerText.RemooveSimbols().ConvertToRuble();
                if (priceTransport < ruble)
                    priceTransport = ruble;
            }
        }
    lock (mResultDictLocker)
    {
        result.TryAdd("PriceTransport", new List<string>() { priceTransport.ToString() });
    }

    result.TryAdd("DescriptionOriginal", new List<string>());
    result.TryAdd("DescriptionTranslate", new List<string>());

}
```

А вот конкретно кусок кода, куда идёт ответ:

```
 private HtmlDocument CheckFirstData(string currentLink)
    {
        var data = UrlWorker.GetDataFromUrl(Constants.cDefaultParsingUrl + currentLink, ProxyWorker.CurrentProxy);
        var htmlDock = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDock.LoadHtml(data);
        return htmlDock;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Тип ошибки "System.OutOfMemoryException" как бы намекает, что заканчивается память. Не нужно СРАЗУ парсить все. Вам необходимо очищать ресурсы, нужно парсить по чуть-чуть, сохранять, чуть-чуть парсить, сохранять.

Comment: Как отчищать ресурсы? GC.Collect?
Т.е. Как я понял мне лучше отказаться от первых Parallel.For и делать паралельно только парсинг самих товаров? Разделение на разные процессы не поможет? Типо под каждую дерикторию свой процесс.

Comment: GC работает автоматически.
Пусть будет несоклько процессов, но должно быть ограничение на количество товаров для "распарсивания" за один раз, распарсил 1000 товаров, записал в вашу базу, дальше парсит, и тд.

Comment: Я товары в памяти не храню, как только я собираю всю информацию о товаре, я его сразу сохраняю

Comment: вот то что метод возвращает "наверх":
return data;

куда это идет? и как обрабатывается? покажите код.

Comment: Добавил код. Три функции, которые парсят продукт в цикле Parallel.For. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: чуть позже посмотрю, пока что на работе завал.